# Cannot read property 'code' of undefined from promise, context api (react hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, api, react-hooks

I am making my first hybrid web app using react hook.
I am faced with a timing problem with promise and context api.

**Here are the logic I am facing with.**

1. A function fetchApplications gets data from firebase firestore, it is defined in globalcontext.js  (called in tableView)
2. tableView.js calls fetchApplications in useEffect.
3. fetchApplications is defined as promise function, I expect it will resolve(return) data until data fetched, it will resolove(return) object like {code:200, data:data}

**problem**
in the fetchData.code,

> Cannot read property 'code' of undefined

**Here is my code**

In the tableview.js

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
      context.fetchApplications(auth.userId, "")
      .then(function (fetchData) {
      console.log("Fetched data: ", fetchData);   ///this is undefined
      if (fetchData.code !== 200) {               /// error part
        alert(fetchData.msg);
      }
      if (!fetchData.data) {
        alert("No applications");
      }
      setsData(fetchData.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

In the GlobalContext.js

```
async function fetchApplications(userId, role) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // resolve({ code: 200, data: "data" });     //If I add this code, it will be alright.

      let dataArray = [];
      let applicationRef = db
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(userId)
        .collection("Applications");
      applicationRef
        .get()
        .then(function (qs) {
          qs.forEach(function (doc) {             //doesn't work
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            console.log(doc.size, " => ", typeof doc);
            dataArray.push(doc.data());
          });
          return Promise.resolve(dataArray);
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("Global, Fetched Data", dataArray);
          if (data) {
            resolve({ code: 200, data: data });
          }
          return;
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
      reject({ code: 400, msg: "시스템에러 고객센터에 문의해주세요" });
    });
  }
```

wrote in codesendbox
If I was write the wrong way of promise, please let me know.
thanks

Comment: I thought that the promise supposed to wait for the api calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're implementing a couple of bad practices and have some major issues. For starters, `fetchApplications` is marked as `async` but you're returning a manually created promise which is quite overkill as your fetching code actually generates a promise **which you should directly return**. Furthermore:

```
.then(function (qs) {
  qs.forEach(function (doc) {             //doesn't work
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    console.log(doc.size, " => ", typeof doc);
    dataArray.push(doc.data());
  });
  return Promise.resolve(dataArray);
})
```

I am not sure what exactly "//doesn't work" should mean but `return Promise.resolve(dataArray);` won't cut it for you. You're already in the `then` chain, so you can't resolve anything from the main promise at this point. You should just pass the data to the next `then` callback as `return dataArray;`.

All in all, I will suggest ditching the `then`-ables syntax all together and migrate to `async`/`await` altogether:

```
async function fetchApplications(userId, role) {
   try {
      const dataArray = [];
      const applicationRef = db
         .collection("Users")
         .doc(userId)
         .collection("Applications");

      const querySnapshot = await applicationRef.get();

      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
         dataArray.push(doc.data());
      });

      return {
         code: 200,
         data: dataArray
      };
   }
   catch (error) {
      return {
         code: 400,
         msg: '시스템에러 고객센터에 문의해주세요'
      };
   }
}
```

Then, in your react component/hook:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   const fetchApplicationDataAsync = async () => {
      const result = await context.fetchApplications(auth.userId, "");

      if (result.code !== 200) {
         alert(result.msg);
      }
      if (!result.data) {
         alert("No applications");
      }

      setsData(result.data);
   }

   fetchApplicationDataAsync();
}, [auth.userId]);
```

Another problem and bad practice is that you're not specifying your dependencies for the `useEffect` hook. You have 2 external dependencies: the `auth.userId` paramater and the `ontext.fetchApplications` function. We alleviate one of the problem by creating the fetch function in the body of `useEffect` itself. However, the `auth.userId` should go into the dependency array as stated above.

Comment: Yes. 1. it is great to review about promise. but that was written during finding which was wrong. I should have review with it. I think I am not well perceived of promise. I should read more about it. 2. that was major problem of my code. auth(context api) was my one of concern. Now I figure how to handle this. I would like to be a good react programmer, it is good to start. thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for `fetchData` to be defined before accessing its properties.

A short form would be

```
if (fetchData && fetchData.code !== 200){...}
```

Applied to your code:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
      context.fetchApplications(auth.userId, "")
      .then(function (fetchData) {
      console.log("Fetched data: ", fetchData);   ///this is undefined
      if (fetchData && fetchData.code !== 200) {               /// error part
        alert(fetchData.msg);
      }else {
        alert("No applications");
      }
      setsData(fetchData.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: yours works. I forgot that I had to check variable contains the right value at the time. I would like to write code that is not to necessary check every value, if I could. anyway you helped me. thank you henk

Comment: @JanghyupLee To be honest, this is a terrible solution as it doesn't solve anything about the even more terrible problem. Avoid building more bad code over yours as it is overly fragile, inefficient and problematic. Just refactor it as it should be.

Comment: in fact, you are right, I didn't check for the core problem here. I guess one of the other two answers should be accepted here

Answer (score 1):

By calling [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) on the `fetchApplications()` function, as follows, you pass to the callback the fullfilment value from the Promise returned by `fetchApplications()` (i.e. `fetchData` gets the value returned by `fetchApplications()`).

```
  context.fetchApplications(auth.userId, "")
  .then(function (fetchData) {...}
```

However, `fetchApplications()` returns a Promise that resolves with `undefined` because, actually, you don't return the [Promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining). This is why you get an error on `fetchData.code`.

Adapting `fetchApplications()` as follows (using `await`, since you use `async`) should do the trick (untested!):

```
  async function fetchApplications(userId, role) {
    try {
      let dataArray = [];
      let applicationRef = db
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('Applications');

      const qs = await applicationRef.get();
      qs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        console.log(doc.size, ' => ', typeof doc);
        dataArray.push(doc.data());
      });
      return { code: 200, data: dataArray };
    } catch (error) {
      return { code: 400, msg: '시스템에러 고객센터에 문의해주세요' };
    }
  }
```

Note that in any case you return an object with a `code` property, so no more problem when doing `fetchData.code`.

Comment: I would like to try your code, because it is legibility and concise. I will let you know the result.